# How does TranslateAnimation work on Android?

Tags: android, android-animation

I went through

```
TranslateAnimation (float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)
```

but am still confused about how `Translate animation` works.

Can someone please explain how it works? I read the docs which say

```
fromXDelta  Change in X coordinate to apply at the start of the animation
toXDelta    Change in X coordinate to apply at the end of the animation
fromYDelta  Change in Y coordinate to apply at the start of the animation
toYDelta    Change in Y coordinate to apply at the end of the animation
```

but it is still not clear to me how it works.

**EDIT**:  I have a `Button` and a `LinearLayout` without any children. When I am clicking on the `Button` I want to dynamically generate a `TextView` and animate that `TextView` to appear in the `LinearLayout`. The number of `TextView`s will depend upon the number of clicks on the Button.

Comment: You mean to say,you have a small button firstly and you want to make it big enough(stretched) to reach a definite position,on click onto that?

Comment: @Hiral no there will be two buttons when we click on first one second one will be visible and animate to a point.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

AFAIK,there would be relative connection between this.

That is,if you want to translate a hidden textview from **right of screen to left of screen**,on click of a button,you actually need to translate it from 100% of X-direction(**right side of screen**) to 0% of X-direction(**left side of screen**).

At this point,you don't need to change Y-direction at all.so that would be 0% for both the options.So finally,you will have:

**fromXDelta**  100%

**toXDelta**    0%

**fromYDelta**  0%

**toYDelta**    0%

you can restrict view of the component by setting this percentages between 0 to 100,as per your requirement.

Similarly,if you need to translate your component on Y-direction as well,then you need to change 0% to some other value.

Hope,its clear to you now.

**EDIT :**

for your requirement,you need to override onclick of button-1,and there you can control button-2's visibility as well as translation.

create animation file in anim folder in your res.

**translate_button.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- translating button from right to left -->
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="900"
    />
</set>
```

now,in your activity file,

```
...

// ll  is linear layout containing button_2
//counter is used to manage visibility of button_2 on click of button_1,i.e.1st click-button_2 would be visible,on 2nd click on button_1,it would be invisible.

//you can change behavior as per your need

button_2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
button_1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        if(counter<1)
        {
            counter++;                  
            button_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Animation anim=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.translate_button);
            button_2.startAnimation(anim);
        }
        else
        {
            counter=0;
            button_2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
});
ll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        if(counter==1)
        {
            counter=0;
            button_2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
});

...
```

Comment: Thanks dear +1 for your answer i will look into it.

Comment: @YasirKhan: you need to change it as per your need.It was just a demo to give you some idea. please try on your own.or post what you tried.

Comment: I have a Button and a LinearLayout without any child in that when i am clicking on the Button i want to generate a dynamic TextView and animate that TextView to the LinearLayout the number of TextViews will depend upon the number of click on the Button.

Comment: then,on click of button,you need to create textview and add it to the linear layout.then you will have to animate that linear layout.or another option is,you will have to create a linear layout containing a textview on click of button.and animate the same linear layout..doing later thing,you would have various linear layout and have contineous effect for textview.

Comment: yeah notion of my question was How does TranslateAnimation works android? because i know the initial coordinates and final coordinates.

Comment: can you tell me what are your initial and final co-ordinates?

Comment: then try with: 
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="50%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="50%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="900"
    />  in translate_button.xml in anim folder.

Comment: Great explanation +1

Answer (score 2):

With TranslateAnimation you can create an animation to control an object.

With TranslateAnimation you're able to control the position of an object.
You pass this 4 parameters, which stand for the X and Y coordinates.

By Example you want to move an object to the **right**, you would do something like:
TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)

(or use `Animation.ABSOLUTE`, `Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF`)

We only use the X coordinate now, because we are doing now an easy "LeftToRight" animation-move.

```
Change in X coordinate to apply at the start of the animation
toXDelta (0.0f)    

Change in X coordinate to apply at the end of the animation (1.0f)
```

= **1 to right**

Maybe take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_system

Comment: Thanks dear +1 for your answer i will look into it.